# How can i window.open different href with different images

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have some restriction within the programme, it would be nice if the

solution doesn't need JQuery, as I have mention above, it does have some

restriction.

What i am trying to achieve is.

1. Change an image with JavaScript dynamically. (Done)
2. Each image will lead to a different link when user click on it. (Need help!)

Below is my current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var image1=new Image()
image1.src="image_1.jpg" 

var image2=new Image()
image2.src="image_2.jpg"

var image3=new Image()
image3.src="image_3.jpg"

var step = 1 

function slideit(){

document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

if(step<3) step++

else step=1

setTimeout("slideit()",2500)

}

slideit()

function inputhref() {

var href = 'https://www.google.ca/';

window.open(href)

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image_1.jpg" name="slide" width="400" height="400" 
 onclick="inputhref()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few errors which I solved, and now it works!

1. [`window.location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) for opening an url in the same window.
2. [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for selecting element(s).
3. Call [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) with function name without using `''`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="image_1.jpg" id="slide" width="100" height="100" 
     onclick="inputhref()">
     
     
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var image1=new Image()
    image1.src="https://image_1.jpg" 

    var image2=new Image()
    image2.src="https://image_2.jpg"

    var image3=new Image()
    image3.src="https://image_3.jpg"
    
    var step = 1 
    var slide = document.querySelector('#slide');
    var timer
 
 function slideit(){
 
 slide.src="https://image_"+step+".jpg"
 
 if(step<3) step++
 
 else step=1
  console.log('Image changed to ' + slide.src);
 timer = setTimeout(slideit,2500)

 }

slideit();

    function inputhref() {

 window.location.href = slide.src;
  clearInterval(timer);
 
 }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object that stores both the image source and the associated link. Also, are you doing anything with those `Image()` classes other than setting and retrieving the source URLs? Because you can just store those as simple strings in the object as well. I would also recommend both storing the step as a property, and keeping all of them in an array to make finding the right one easier.

Something like:

```
var images = [
    {
        step: 1,
        src: "image_1.jpg",
        link: "http://example.com/image1-link",
    },
    {
        step: 2,
        src: "image_2.jpg",
        link: "http://example.com/image2-link",
    },
    // Repeat as necessary
]
```

And then you can change your functions accordingly:

```
function slideit() {
    var correctImage = images.find(image => image.step == step);
    document.images.slide.src = correctImage.src;
    // rest is unchanged
}

function inputhref(step) {
    var correctImage = images.find(image => image.step == step);
    window.open(correctImage.link);
}
```